# Files listed on WinShock (KB2992611) what do the different file sizes for the same file name mean?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, patch-management

```
Lsass.exe.mui   6.0.6002.23498  10,752  20-Sep-2014 03:46   Not applicable
Lsasrv.dll.mui  6.0.6002.23498  50,688  20-Sep-2014 03:33   Not applicable
Lsass.exe.mui   6.0.6002.23498  10,752  20-Sep-2014 03:35   Not applicable
Lsasrv.dll.mui  6.0.6002.23498  52,224  20-Sep-2014 03:31   Not applicable
Lsass.exe.mui   6.0.6002.23498  10,752  20-Sep-2014 03:32   Not applicable
Lsasrv.dll.mui  6.0.6002.23498  59,904  20-Sep-2014 02:03   Not applicable
Lsass.exe.mui   6.0.6002.23498  10,752  20-Sep-2014 02:05   Not applicable
Lsasrv.dll.mui  6.0.6002.23498  60,928  20-Sep-2014 03:34   Not applicable
Lsass.exe.mui   6.0.6002.23498  11,264  20-Sep-2014 03:35   Not applicable
Lsasrv.dll.mui  6.0.6002.23498  49,664  20-Sep-2014 00:32   Not applicable
Lsass.exe.mui   6.0.6002.23498  8,192   20-Sep-2014 00:34   Not applicable
Lsasrv.dll.mui  6.0.6002.23498  55,808  20-Sep-2014 02:49   Not applicable
Lsass.exe.mui   6.0.6002.23498  10,752  20-Sep-2014 02:50   Not applicable
Lsasrv.dll.mui  6.0.6002.23498  51,200  20-Sep-2014 02:04   Not applicable
Lsass.exe.mui   6.0.6002.23498  10,752  20-Sep-2014 02:05   Not applicable
Lsasrv.dll.mui  6.0.6002.23498  59,392  20-Sep-2014 02:15   Not applicable
Lsass.exe.mui   6.0.6002.23498  10,752  20-Sep-2014 02:16   Not applicable
```

Comment: Some more context on this would be helpful. Where did you copy/paste this from?

Comment: Considering the file extension I would assume these are files with language-specific resources.

Comment: I don't know, but the lsass.exe executable on all my webfarm servers have been hitting high CPU since this KB2992611 patch.  It's really bad.

Comment: this is where is extracted the information in the post, from the file information section https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2992611/en-us

Answer (score 1):

I tend to think you're seeing different language versions of the files but without some context on where you copy/pasted this from it's not something I can be 100% sure about.